# How to transform from RACSignal(the Objective-C version) to Signal (the Swift version)

Tags: swift, reactive-cocoa-3

e.g. How to convert cell.rac_prepareForReuseSignal to a Signal?

```
levelSignal
|> takeUntil( doSomeThingTo(cell.rac_prepareForReuseSignal) )
|> observe(next: { level in
    ...
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you to transform it to `Signal`? `Signal` is hot, already subscribed, while `RACSignal` is usually cold and only ready to subscribe.

You might rather transform it to the `SignalProducer`, so use `toSignalProducer` method.

[Here is official documentation about these transformations](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#objective-c-bridging)